# Ввод и вывод "сложных данных" в олимпиадных задачах

Tags: c#, олимпиада, файловый-ввод-вывод

Можно ли используя классы StreamReader,StreamWriter обеспечить корректный ввод-вывод для прохождения тестов на Eolymp?
В Интернете есть пример использования этого метода для решения задач, однако мне не ясно: где и как создавать те самые файлы "saloon.in" , "saloon.out" из фрагментов кода:

```
//Ввод
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("saloon.in");
            int N = Convert.ToInt32(sr.ReadLine());
           
            DateTime[] input = new DateTime[N];
            int[] impatience = new int[N];
   
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
              string[] client = sr.ReadLine().Split(' ');
              input[i] = new DateTime(1, 1, 1,
              Convert.ToInt32(client[0]), Convert.ToInt32(client[1]), 0);
              impatience[i] = Convert.ToInt32(client[2]);
            }
//Вывод
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("saloon.out");
          
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                sw.WriteLine(output[i].Hour + " " + output[i].Minute);
            sw.Close();
```

Компилятор предлагает по адресу: 'C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\TestApp\TestApp\bin\Release\net6.0\saloon.in'.

Я попробовал создать файл блокнота со входящими данными и пустой для выходящих, но ошибка остаётся.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я недописал или сделал неправильно? Можно ли решить задачу ввода-вывода проще, элегантнее?

Comment: путь считается относительно папки где запущена программа. В тестовых системах файлы с данным обычно лежат вместе с запускаемым файлом

Comment: к слову, для удобства, в данном случае, можно использовать консоль, подменив ей поток вывода и ввода

Comment: @Grundy Спасибо!

Comment: @iiKuzmychov Спасибо!